# Access previous values within object during declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, accessibility, self

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

```
var obj = {
    value: 10,
    value2: value + 2
};
```

How can I do the above? (Assuming it's even possible)

I am using a lot of jQuery's `$.extend` to add more properties that rely on the previous values being added; so that modifying a few values automatically correct the rest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations) and [Object referencing its own property on initilization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433395/object-referencing-its-own-property-on-initilization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in declaration, but you could always make a function. The following will always return a value 2 greater than that stored in value:

```
var obj = {
    value: 10,
    getValue2: function(){ return this.value + 2; }
};
```

If you don't want the value of value2 to change along with value, you could declare a placeholder variable and declare the object using that:

```
var placeholder = 10;

var obj = {
    value: placeholder,
    value2: placeholder + 2
};
```

Comment: building on this answer, you could make value and value2 private variables and provide obj with a generic "get" function.

Comment: That should be `this.value` else you get error: `'value' is undefined`.

Comment: @gilly3 - Meant to have it there...typo. Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: One point that should be made is that the two aren't functionally equivelant.  In the first example, after initialization, `obj.value2` is unrelated to `obj.value`.  But, in your solution, when you increment `obj.value`, the result of `obj.getValue2()` is also incremented.  http://jsfiddle.net/8zWNs/

Comment: @gilly3 - That's true, but if the OP truly wanted the behavior that you're talking about it would be easy enough to define the object without referencing a previous value.

Comment: Right, absolutely.  If the values should be tied together, a function is absolutely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if you can do this at the time of declaration.  You could, however, do it afterwards:

using extend:

```
var obj = {
    value: 10
};

$.extend(obj, {
    value2: obj.value + 2
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KgKgf/

just javascript:

```
var obj = {
    value: 10
};

obj.value2 = obj.value + 2;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KgKgf/1/

Comment: Holy smokes, why would anyone use `.extend()` just to add a property to an object?  Way overkill!  Your second example is correct, but that first one is ... silly.

Comment: @gilly3 i agree that it is not the proper tool for this job, but the OP mentioned he was using extend to add properties so i figured i would show an example using extend.

Comment: Fair enough... I missed that part in his question.

Comment: @gilly3 thank you for removing your downvote :D