# Reference property when creating object

Tags: javascript, object

How can I reference a property of an object when creating the object itself? Example below which doesn't work:

```
var object = {

  prop1 : $(this).find('.foo');
  prop2 : this.prop1.find('.bar');

}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible (to reference the object - or properties therein - created by the object literal from within itself). Yes, this is a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry it's a duplicate. I did search. What is the common way around this?

Comment: Ahh, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433395/object-referencing-its-own-property-on-initilization?lq=1

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396518/how-to-reference-a-key-from-the-same-object-when-creating-it?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new keyword with an anonymous function:

```
var $self = $(this);

var object = new function () {

  this.prop1 = $self.find('.foo');
  this.prop2 = this.prop1.find('.bar');

};
```

Technically that object will have a different `constructor` property than the object literal would, but that is unlikely to cause an issue for most use cases.

As a simple demonstration:

```
var obj = new function () {
  this.x = 7;
  this.y = this.x * 2;
};

console.log(obj); // Object {x: 7, y: 14}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer a property of the object which is not yet created. You can have a function which will be called after the creation of object. So then you can refer a `property` using `this`.

Like bellow:-

```
obj = {
   a1:3,
   a2:function(){return this.a1}
};
```

so calling `obj.a2()` will return `3` here.

Or if you don't want to call is like a `function` use [Get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get)

```
obj = {
   a1:3,
   get a2(){return this.a1}
};

obj.a2; //returns 3
```

Basically what `get` does **It binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.**

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

```
 var obj = {
 prop1 : $(this).find('.foo');
 prop2 : function() { return this.prop2.find('.bar'); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're interested in avoiding recalculating `$(this).find('.foo')`, in which case you could do something like:

```
var object = (function() {

  var prop1 = $(this).find('.foo'),
      prop2 = prop1.find('bar');

  return {
    prop1: prop1,
    prop2: prop2
  };

}.bind(this);
```